# Stop Geary automatic download images

Tags: pantheon-mail

I have Geary installed on ElementaryOS Freya and I have ran all updates since 22-5-2016. I have configured Gmail and got it up and running. However, I do not like automatic downloads of pictures, especially not in the Junk folder. The Settings of Geary seem very limited and don't include this options. Is this hidden somewhere or just not possible at the moment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This feature was implemented in the version of Mail that ships with Loki. The solution is to upgrade to the latest release of elementary OS